# sql server pivot : group by with dynamic columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, pivot, dynamic-columns

I have done a pivot on a table, generating dynamic columns :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Replace(variable,char(CAST(0x0016 as int)),'')) val
                      FROM TABLEDATA
                      ORDER BY val asc
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query =

'SELECT
  time,
  country,
  disease,
  ' + @cols + '
FROM
  TABLEDATA
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(value) 
  FOR variable IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p; ';

 execute(@query);
```

It returns the following result :

```
time | country | disease | indicateur1 | indicateur2 | ... | indicateur14 | ... | indicateurn
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2001 | FRANCE  | MAL     | 0.003       |             |     |              |     |
2002 | FRANCE  | AID     |             | 0.45        |     |              |     |
1997 | ITALY   | HIV     | 0.307       |             |     |              |     |
1999 | ROMANIA | MAL     | 1.044       |             |     |              |     |
2003 | ROMANIA | AID     |             |             |     | 0.77         |     |
2003 | ROMANIA | AID     | 0.872       |             |     |              |     |
2004 | ROMANIA | HIV     |             | 0.921       |     |              |     |
2002 | IRELAND | MAL     |             | 0.008       |     |              |     |
```

But I need to group by the first 3 columns to get the following :

```
time | country | disease | indicateur1 | indicateur2 | ... | indicateur14 | ... | indicateurn
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2001 | FRANCE  | MAL     | 0.003       |             |     |              |     |
2002 | FRANCE  | AID     |             | 0.45        |     |              |     |
1997 | ITALY   | HIV     | 0.307       |             |     |              |     |
1999 | ROMANIA | MAL     | 1.044       |             |     |              |     |
2003 | ROMANIA | AID     | 0.872       |             |     | 0.77         |     |
2004 | ROMANIA | HIV     |             | 0.921       |     |              |     |
2002 | IRELAND | MAL     |             | 0.008       |     |              |     |
```

So I need to `group by time, country, disease`, but as my columns from the pivot are dynamics, I can't manage to find a solution...

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81618f/1/0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' +
                        QUOTENAME(Replace(variable,char(CAST(0x0016 as int)),'')) val
                      FROM TABLEDATA
                      ORDER BY val asc
                      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
                     ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
                        , 1, 1, '');

SELECT @query =

'SELECT
  time,
  country,
  disease,
  ' + @cols + '
FROM (
    Select
        time,
        country,
        disease,
        variable,
        convert(decimal(10, 2), value) as value
    From
        TABLEDATA
    ) t
PIVOT 
(
  Sum(value)
  FOR variable IN( ' + @cols + ' )' +
' ) AS p; ';


Execute(@query);
```

**<kbd>[Example Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81618f/59)</kbd>**

Comment: Nice trick I should have thought about! I kept `max(value)` instead of `convert` + `sum(value)`

Comment: I've misdirected you, it still works with `max`. The actual trick is removing `pgroup1`, `pgroup2`, `pgroup3` from the from clause. `Sum` is only necessary if you have multiple rows with the same `time, country, disease, variable`