# How to pivot table with complex condition?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, pivot-table

I have a table with sample data

```
ProID   ProNum      TranDate
12      123         2017-12-12 08:04:00.000
12      140         2017-12-12 08:15:00.000
12      290         2017-12-12 09:15:00.000
13      100         2017-12-12 09:15:00.000
13      200         2017-12-12 10:59:00.000
12      50          2017-12-13 06:04:00.000
12      250         2017-12-13 08:00:00.000
```

I want to calculator and then pivot table, sample I want value in each time zone, I must calculator in each period hour, `max[hourNext] - max[hourPre]`

```
ProCode      TranDate      [05-06] [06-07] [07-08] [08-09] [09-10]
12           2017/12/12    0       0       140     150     0
12           2017/12/13    50      0       200     0       0
13           2017/12/12    0       0       0       100     100
```

I see ref as [sql server pivot : group by with dynamic columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914735/sql-server-pivot-group-by-with-dynamic-columns). But the problem of me as calculator `max[hourNext] - max[hourPre]`. If the previous time zone value does not exist, it automatically rollback the previous time zone value.

Comment: Couple of questions. Firstly, will the columns only ever be those supplied? `[05-06] [06-07] [07-08] [08-09] [09-10]`? Secondly, I noticed that your data to proID 13 has a ProNum of 200, however, proCode13 contains no columns with the value 200. Where has this data gone?

Comment: And where did ProNum 123 go? I don't understand what hourNext and hourPre are. Can you explain what that is?

Comment: Dear Larnu, In fact , so I have 24 period in a day , sample ```[00-01][01-02]....[23-00]```. Second, data of ProID13 has 100, you can see range ```max[hour9] - max[hour8] (100 - 0)``` , and ```max[hour10] - max[hour9] (200-100)``` .

Comment: Dear Sean Lange, In fact , i have 24 period , and i will calculator data in each period , the value as `max[hour] - max[hour]` , sample , value of range ```[08-09] is 100 (100-0) , range [09-10] is 100 (200-100)```